# PhoneCallTask always prompts

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

This is regarding `PhoneCallTask` for Windows Phone 8.

I was planning on making an emergency app for the windows phone and tried using `PhoneCallTask`. It does the job. I managed to get it working by adding:

```
PhoneCallTask call = new PhoneCallTask();
call.DisplayName = "Name";
call.PhoneNumber = "0123456789";
call.Show();
```

This is well and good but there is one thing that really frustrates me. The whole point of this app is to be quick and call when you need to just like the normal Phone call app.

Now whenever I click the call button a messagebox appears saying whether I want to dial the number. This is really annoying. I was just wondering if there was a way to get rid of it and go straight to the call?

Comment: It sounds like a security feature. I wouldn't want some random app to be able to make calls without any authorization. Think of the potential for abuse..

Comment: That is a good point but there has to be a way. Apps like Skype and Viber sure seem to be doing this quite well?

Comment: @Ahmed.C Look who had [bought Skype](http://www.wired.com/business/2011/05/microsoft-buys-skype-2/)

Comment: @Romasz Ahaha...Microsoft...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

As it is said at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394025%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> Use the phone call task to enable users to make a phone call from your application. The phone call task launches the Phone application and displays the phone number and display name that you specify. The phone call is not placed until the user presses the call button.

The method [Show()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.phonecalltask.show%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) only shows the Phone application.

Imagine that it wouldn't be suitable if an App could for example dial other numbers (especially expensive).

Comment: So it seems that it's not possible? I'd have to always click the "dial" button every time ;(

Comment: @Ahmed.C Unless you have better privileges, I think it is like this.